# Can I build iOS/Android apps using Azure?

Tags: azure

I would like to know **if I can build iOS/Android apps via Azure**? I have several web projects there, and it would be great to have automated builds for mobile apps in one place.

There are mobile services, but it isn't that I want - it's just API for iOS and Android apps.

Comment: I don't understand what, exactly, you're asking. Any iOS / Android app may interact with Azure-based services via the API you create+expose. You still have to have a mobile app, and *something* running in Azure to provide the API support. Again, I'm not sure what you're seeking.

Comment: I'm searching for an opportunity to build my code from github or bitbucket on Azure, and then get link to buld file (apk, for example). So, just looking for Continues Deployment for ios/android on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The very fact that Azure apps run on Azure means they can't be on iOS devices, so your question is a little confusing as iOS and Azure are mutually exclusive.  Azure is a platform for building websites. It can't even host Windows Desktop apps, let alone native iOS or Android mobile apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  You can run a VM to use Jenkins (or other CI services) to automate the build process.  However you will still need an iOS machine to do the build of your app.  You can have this as a machine that is triggered by your cloud server.

With Android and Windows Phone it's pretty easy - the build can happen on the same Windows box as the CI service.

You can find more information on automating iOS builds here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/.